# My OnItemclicklistener is not working: I am calling Itemclicklistener from on click listener but it's not working

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I am trying show popup on image click listener and from that popup I want fetch value but I am not getting value from popup.
I am calling Itemclicklistener from on click listener but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view.getId()==R.id.imgv_search)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)Home.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View show_menu_popup = inflator.inflate(R.layout.popup_list, null);
        ListView listv_problems = (ListView) show_menu_popup.findViewById(R.id.listv_problems);
        AdapterCity city = new AdapterCity(Home.this,al_cityid,al_cityname);
        listv_problems.setAdapter(city);
        Dialog dialog_menus = new Dialog(Home.this);
        dialog_menus.setTitle("Select city : ");
        dialog_menus.setContentView(show_menu_popup);
        dialog_menus.show();
        listv_problems.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"City is changed : "+edt_city_name.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my OnItemclickListener:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
{
    if(adapterView.getId()== R.id.listv_problems)
    {
        //TextView cityid= (TextView)adapterView.findViewById(R.id.cityid);
        //String city_id=  cityid.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(Home.this,"You click popup",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Dialog` getting opened?

Comment: does it display toast?

Comment: you have to switch these lines: `dialog_menus.show();` and `listv_problems.setOnItemClickListener(this);`. Because the show method is synchronous, such that it returns only **after** the popup is closed...and therefore no listener is registered yet

Comment: Yes dialog is getting open

Comment: No its not displaying toast

Comment: i have switched dialog_menus.show(); and listv_problems.setOnItemClickListener(this); but still not getting result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

    al_citynames.get(position);
    //this will give you the value of city
    Toast.makeText(Home.this,"You click popup",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

}
```

Or you can use `view.getitembyposition()` inside `onItemClick();`

Comment: It dos not displaying toast.

Comment: Did you tried setting onclick in your adapter... May be that will work